# "Backward ran sentences until reeled the mind." What does this sentence mean?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Do your best to be lucid.
>
> ("I see but one rule: to be clear", Stendhal.)
>   Simple sentences help. Keep complicated constructions and
>   gimmicks to a minimum, if necessary by remembering the New
>   Yorker's comment: "***Backward ran sentences until reeled the
>   mind.***"

The paragraph above is an excerpt from *The Economist Style Guide*(11th edition).

The last sentence is confusing. It is hard to understand even if I looked up all the words in it. Could someone please paraphrase it or explain its grammar? Thank you.

Comment: This is a send-up or caricature of the way Time magazine (historically) phrased sentences. It was infamous for its unusual grammar, overuse of a handful of adjectives, and eschewing articles (*the* and *a*). The sentence means "[I'm tired of the way Time Magazine writes because the] sentences run backwards, until my mind reels [i.e. I'm confused or baffled, like a punch-drunk prize fighter]".

Comment: It's a self-referential sentence, in that it uses the structure it references (sentences running backward, that is, being organized (Object-Verb-Subject) instead of the normal (Subject-Verb-Object)).  If you reorganize it into standard format, it says "Sentences ran backwards until the mind reeled."

Comment: No, @Hellion; the two clauses are Adverb-Verb-Subject and Verb-Subject respectively. Both clauses are intransitive, so no objects.

Comment: @BrianDonovan true, I purposely oversimplified.  SVO is the standard for sentence order, I went with it instead of matching the actual parts of speech exactly.

Comment: @Hellion Thank you very much for your explanations. Such abnormal sentence structure is really peculiar and had better be avoided in writing. :)

Comment: @Hellion I hate asking others to do work for my benefit, but could you elaborate on the grammatical aspects in an answer? Sounds like I have something really interesting to learn here. You're guaranteed one upvote, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hellion](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2490/hellion) mentioned, the sentence was designed to be confusing by reversing the order in English to verb-subject. Normally, our sentences are ordered by subject-verb-object.

If you set the order to our normal usage, the meaning is clear. "Backward ran sentences until reeled the mind," turns into, "**Sentences ran backward until the mind reeled.**"

Comment: It's worth noting that the order isn't actually wrong, just unusual, especially twice in the same sentence.

Comment: True! I corrected my wording from "right." There are some conjugations, however, that definitely call for SVO order (e.g., "Mice eat cats," would definitely be wrong).

Comment: Inversion to VS order can be triggered by certain adverbial constructions at the start of the clause. There's also OSV which is not inversion, like "Helms, too, they chose" or "Rice mice eat, but mice cats eat".  It's a stylistic choice, best used for occasional emphasis or variation.